# Numpy inaccurate matrix inverse

Tags: numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I have been getting seemingly unacceptably high inaccuracies when computing matrix inverses (solving a linear system) in numpy.

- Is this a normal level of inaccuracy?
- How can I improve the accuracy of this computation?
- Also, is there a way to solve this system more efficiently in numpy or scipy (`scipy.linalg.cho_solve` seemed promising but does not do what I want)?

In the code below, `cholM` is a 128 x 128 matrix. The matrix data is too large to include here but is located on pastebin: [cholM.txt](http://pastebin.com/hzsnbgJ3).

Also, the original vector, `ovec`, is being randomly selected, so for different `ovec`'s the accuracy varies, but, for most cases, the error still seems unacceptably high.

**Edit** Solving the system using the singular value decomposition produces significantly lower error than the other methods.

```
import numpy.random as rnd
import numpy.linalg as lin
import numpy as np

cholM=np.loadtxt('cholM.txt')

dims=len(cholM)
print 'Dimensions',dims

ovec=rnd.normal(size=dims)
rvec=np.dot(cholM.T,ovec)
invCholM=lin.inv(cholM.T)

svec=np.dot(invCholM,rvec)
svec1=lin.solve(cholM.T,rvec)

def back_substitute(M,v):
    r=np.zeros(len(v))
    k=len(v)-1
    r[k]=v[k]/M[k,k]
    for k in xrange(len(v)-2,-1,-1):
        r[k]=(v[k]-np.dot(M[k,k+1:],r[k+1:]))/M[k,k]

    return r

svec2=back_substitute(cholM.T,rvec)

u,s,v=lin.svd(cholM)
svec3=np.dot(u,np.dot(np.diag(1./s),np.dot(v,rvec)))

for k in xrange(dims):
    print '%20.3f%20.3f%20.3f%20.3f'%(ovec[k]-svec[k],ovec[k]-svec1[k],ovec[k]-svec2[k],ovec[k]-svec3[k])

assert np.all( np.abs(ovec-svec)<1e-5 ) 
assert np.all( np.abs(ovec-svec1)<1e-5 )
```

Comment: Typically this is a sign that your matrix is ill conditioned.  For the lower triangular matrix you provided it appears that the ratio of the largest to smallest singular values (the condition number) is about 10^16. This is definitely a problem.

Comment: Why would condition number matter here? I am taking an inverse, so normally, I would be worried if the matrix was near singular. The `cholM` matrix is triangular, so very small values on the diagonal would certainly affect the solution, but this is not occuring.

Comment: You could try to multiply cholM and invCholM, then subtract the identity matrix to convince yourself whether condition number matters or not

Comment: This is essentially the same thing I did in the code included in the example.

Comment: Is there a difference in accuracy using `inv` versus `solve`?

Comment: Yes. There is also a difference between inv, solve, and direct back substitution. The error in inv seems greater (as expected), but solve and back substitution seem about the same.

Comment: Either the condition number or the smallest eigenvalue of `cholM` does seem to make a difference. The smallest and largest eigenvalues of `cholM` are 0.0656032562256 and 2.92811965942 respectively, giving a condition number of about 44.6 .

Comment: The condition number [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) measures the maximum error you can get. So it will undoubtedly give a faithful estimate of the accuracy of naive back-substitution. The condition number for the matrix you provide is ~1e16, not 44.6. Eigenvalues do not in general give you the condition number, except for normal matrices (which cholM is clearly not).

Comment: There appears to be a miscommunication here. Condition numbers don't affect the solution in the world of mathematics; they do affect the solution in the world of computer science. A condition number of 1e16 is definitely bad news. Make sure you are using double precision for starters. If that does not help; different ways of solving the same system can have wildly different sensitivity to numerical error. That backsubsitution im seeing there is also squarely in the 'don't try this in the context of bad conditioning' camp.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @Craig J Copi and @pv, the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of the `cholM` matrix is high, around 10^16, indicating that to achieve higher accuracy in the inverse, much greater numerical precision may be required.

Condition number can be determined by the ratio of maximum singular value to minimum singular value. In this instance, this ratio is not the same as the ratio of eigenvalues.

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/linalg.html

> We could find the solution vector using a matrix inverse:
>   ...
>   However, it is better to use the linalg.solve command which can be faster and more numerically stable

edit - from Steve Lord at MATLAB
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/63130

> Why are you inverting? If you're inverting to solve a system, don't -- 
>   generally you would want to use backslash instead.
>
> However, for a system with a condition number around 1e17 (condition numbers
>   must be greater than or equal to 1, so I assume that the 1e-17 figure in
>   your post is the reciprocal condition number from RCOND) you're not going to
>   get a very accurate result in any case.